# how can I use --dry-run option in clang-format?

Tags: clang, clang-format

my os is ubuntu 16.04 and I want to use --dry-run option included in clang-format.
but when I write `clang-format --help` on terminal, it doesn't have --dry-run option.
as I guess it's because of version. when I write `sudo apt-get install clang-format` I shows me installing clang-format-3.8.
so I wonder

1. the reason that clang-format does not have --dry-run option is due to version?
   2-1. if first question is yes, Is there any way that I can install clang-format version over 10?
   2-2. if first question is no, how can I use --dry-run option?

Answer (score 0):

> the reason that clang-format does not have --dry-run option is due to version?

Yes, `--dry-run` was added [in Nov
2019](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/4c44fd3de374fdce383ca1b0313b2418d1f1d370)
when Clang 10.0.0 came out.

> if first question is yes, Is there any way that I can install
> clang-format version over 10

You could either upgrade your Ubuntu installation as clang-format 10
is [available in newer
systems](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=clang-format-10)
or build it manually but the easiest and most preferred way these days
is to run official [Ubuntu docker
image](https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu):

```
$ docker run -it ubuntu
root@502d5d8cfb26:/# head -n2 /etc/os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
root@502d5d8cfb26:/# apt-get update
root@502d5d8cfb26:/# apt-get -y install clang-format
root@502d5d8cfb26:/# clang-format --version
clang-format version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1
root@502d5d8cfb26:/# clang-format --help | grep -- '--dry-run'
  --dry-run                  - If set, do not actually make the formatting changes
  --ferror-limit=<uint>      - Set the maximum number of clang-format errors to emit before stopping (0 = no limit). Used only with --dry-run or -n
  -n                         - Alias for --dry-run
```

Comment: wow! thanks a lot. actually I installed it on Windows. but I will try your suggestion thanks a lot. if you know about jenkins, could you answer to my another question? if you can I really appreciate about it

Comment: wow.. thank you so much!! actually I installed on windows, but I will try your suggestion. if you know about jenkins, could you help my another question? I am really new jenkins and clang-format, so I am really confused.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66299757/can-i-upload-xml-report-on-jenkins

Comment: On StackOverflow you thank by accepting the answer. See [What should I
do when someone answers my
question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)